# Получить имя сетевого интерфейса в linux

Tags: c++, linux, сокет

Начал выкладывать свою библиотеку: https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource , возникла проблема в примере mping.

Для получения ответов от пингуемого хоста нужно включить прослушивание интерфейса. В коде по умолчанию используется интерфейс eth0, которого вполне может и не быть. Собственно на VPS где проверяется работоспособность этого интерфейса нет, вследствие чего возникает ошибка.

Текущая реализация: https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/blob/master/msvcore/net/sniffer.h#L56 и https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/blob/master/msvcore/net/sniffer.h#L96

```
unsigned char device[1024];
strcpy((char*)device, "eth0");
strcpy((char*)interface.ifr_name,(char*)device);
if(ioctl(sock,SIOCGIFFLAGS,&interface)<0){ printf("failed reading data for %s!\n",device); return 1; }
```

Так как интерфейса eth0 в системе нет, вылетает ошибка "failed reading data for eth0".

Как получить имя интерфейса существующего интерфейса? Так, чтобы у интерфейса был реальный ip. Как вариант, можно передавать в функцию локальный ip с которого послан пинг, тогда как получить название интерфейса зная его ip?

Код старый, написан коряво, переписывать смысла нет, а работоспособность восстановить хочется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

думаю, вам подойдёт функция `getifaddrs`.

описание и пример применения смотрите командой

```
$ man getifaddrs
```

либо в [интернете](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)

Comment: Ага, уже пользуюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Утилита `ifconfig` возвращает список интерфейсов, их состояние и адреса на них. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951257/using-c-code-to-get-same-info-as-ifconfig) пишут как получить тот же результат не вызывая стороннюю программу.

Comment: @mikelsv, суть ссылки -- читайте [man netdevice](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice) или сорсы ifconfig

Comment: Да, именно так. Если хочется сделать быстро, вызови готовую утилиту. Если не хочется зависеть от сторонней программы, надо скопировать реализацию оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

Можно посмотреть в файле конфигураций:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Или выполнить команду:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Comment: Это костыли. Вызвать команду, распарсить вывод.